# Selenium + Python ActionChains or PyAutoGUI "Ctrl + S" doesnt work on a web-based PDF

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pyautogui, save-as

I'm trying to write a program using Selenium which can continually loop through a webpage, click on dropdown menu links based on the town, month and year which opens up a web-based pdf. From there, I would like to save the pdf using "Ctrl + s" via Selenium ActionChains or PyAutoGUI hotkeys. Regardless of the many posts I've seen that suggested using these methods, I can't even get as much as the save window to pop up once the program is running. I'm aware that Selenium can't interact with the OS and the closest I could get is to use the ActionChain's to simulate a "ctrl + s" function and save to a folder. However, it seems like recent updates to Selenium and or Chrome Webdrivers have left these methods obsolete.

[image: Here is what the pdf looks like]

Just to add context, I've only been coding for about six months now. There could be things I'm overlooking and or misunderstanding about how to use these methods. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Using:
Selenium, Chrome and PyCharm

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
from sys import path
import pdfkit
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains



options = Options()
s = {"savefile.default_directory" : 'C:\\Users\\My_Name\\Desktop\\Selenium Temp Folder'}
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", s)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
url = 'https://www.website.com'
driver.get(url)
    
'''

Other class code is written before this. Below is the base code of the loop. What follows after are all the different methods of I've tried.

'''
        
for town in self.__towns:
    dropdown1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='lmuArea']")
    dropdown1.click()
    target_town = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='"+ town + "']")
    target_town.click()
    for year in self.__years:
        for month_num, month in self.__months.items():
            dropdown2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='lmuTime']"))
                                    )
                        dropdown2.click()
                        try:
                            target_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                                          EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='lmuTime']//option[@value='" + year + "-" + month_num + "'][normalize-space()='" + month + ' ' + year + "']"))
)
                                        target_date.click()
                                        view_report = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@rel='lmu']//button[contains(text(),'View Report')]")
                                        view_report.click()
                                        tabs = driver.window_handles
                                        driver.switch_to.window(tabs[1])
```

Try 1: Use pdfkit to turn new window to a pdf and save
Im not sure if this just creates another web-based pdf page or can actually be used to save the pdf in a folder.

```
pdfkit.from_url(driver.current_url, 'New_Name.pdf', configuration=self.__config)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
```

Try 2: Simulating ctrl + s using Selenium ActionChains. I expected this method to at least produce the save window popup window, but it doesn't.

```
ActionChains(driver)\
   .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
   .send_keys('s')\
   .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
   .perform()
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
```

Try 3: Simulating ctrl + s using PyAutoGUI hotkeys. This method doesn't produce the save window popup either.

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')  # Press the Ctrl-S hotkey combination to save the pdf
pyautogui.write(town + ' ' + month + ' ' + year) #Would create the document title using the town, month and year 
pyautogui.press('enter')
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
```

Try 4: Completely bypass saving a pdf document and try to copy and paste the contents of the document using Pyperclip. All Pdf contents were selected using the "Ctrl + a" ActionChain but was not copied into the variable. Not sure if the "Ctrl + C" doesn't work or if I'm using Pyperclip wrong.

```
ActionChains(driver)\
   .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
   .send_keys('a')\
   .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
   .perform()
text1 = ActionChains(driver)\
          .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
          .send_keys('c') \
          .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
          .perform()
text2 = pyperclip.copy(text1)
pyperclip.waitForPaste()
text2 = pyperclip.paste()
print(text2)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
```

Try 5: Attempt #2 of saving a pdf document and try to copy and paste the contents of the document using strictly ActionChains.

```
ActionChains(driver)\
  .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
  .send_keys('a')\
  .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
  .perform()
ActionChains(driver)\
  .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
  .send_keys('c') \
  .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
  .perform()
text = ActionChains(driver)\
         .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
         .send_keys('v')\
         .key_up(Keys.CONTROL)\
         .perform()
print(text)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
```

Comment: take the url of the pdf and then run `import urllib.request` and `urllib.request.urlretrieve(pdf_url, "test.pdf")`

Comment: I appreciate your help @soundwave . Urlretrieve allowed me to download an actual file but I believe it's being corrupted in the save process. The following message occurs when trying to open the file: Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'test.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasnt corectly downloaded). I'll continue down this route to see if there's a fix

Comment: `pyautogui` works only on the current active window, so are you sure that the browser window is active when `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')` is executed? Moreover, if you manually do CTRL+S does the popup appear?

Comment: Manual CTRL + S always works even when I detach the Selenium browser window. I'm almost positive the current browser is active as well. I've been print debugging through each iteration to make sure the current window is where the pdf opens up.

Comment: But with "current window" you mean the window you switched to using `driver.switch_to.window()` or the window which has the focus (i.e. window on top of every other windows)? Just before the command `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')` place these commands `import win32gui, win32process, psutil` and `pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())` and `print(psutil.Process(pid[-1]).name())` then execute the script and let me know what process is printed